# Oracle Stored Procedure Compilation error during alter table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1
AS
  strSchema VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEA_CONTRAINT ';
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEB_CONTRAINT ';
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_C DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEC_CONTRAINT ';
COMMIT;

END test1;
```

But I'm getting the following error during compilation, not sure why.

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER TABLE " when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
>     null pragma raise return select update while with
>      
>      << continue close current delete fetch lock
>     insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
>     merge pipe purge
>
> The symbol "(" was substituted for "ALTER TABLE " to continue.

Comment: You need to think again before (ab)using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. You should do it in pure **SQL**, what is the need to do it in **PL/SQL** at all? On a side note, 1. You declared a variable and never use it. 2. no need to use `COMMIT` for `DDL`.

Comment: hi, i did it in store procedure is because i need to schedule a queue to run it(i dont run it manually hence i dont do it in pure sql), for the variable, i did use but didnt show the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. There is no need to `COMMIT` actually. `ALTER TABLE` is a DDL Statement which does not need to be committed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1
AS
  strSchema VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEA_CONTRAINT ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEB_CONTRAINT ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_C DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEC_CONTRAINT ';
COMMIT;

END test1;
```

Comment: do not forget to accept the answer correct and upvote when you like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One command in one EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1
AS
  strSchema VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEA_CONTRAINT ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEB_CONTRAINT ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE TABLE_C DISABLE CONSTRAINT TABLEC_CONTRAINT ';

END test1;
```

Comment: No need of `COMMIT` for `DDL`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Yes, thanks. Just copy from question :)